# Is there something like rc.local in systemd?

Tags: systemd, rc

Back with system V init there was a script called rc.local where you could stuff commands that needed to be run during bootup, which would not fit to one particular service. Does systemd have a similar mechanism?

Comment: You can still use `rc.local`